# Difference Between yellow and blue User Account Control window (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, uac

What's the difference between these two UAC popups?

[Blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OC9VC.png)
[Yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izAO8.png)

I see the yellow one all the time, so it doesn't seem as important as the blue one. But I just noticed that they basically say the same thing.

Comment: The blue prompt isn't actually a UAC prompt. Only the yellow one is a UAC prompt.

Comment: There _is,_ however, also a blue UAC prompt, and that cmd.exe one really ought to have had a blue header if it was a legitimate cmd.exe file.

Comment: @Ramhound but what is the difference?

Comment: @Muffined - One is a UAC prompt the other is a Microsoft Defender Smart Screen prompt. What do you mean what’s the difference? Like I said one is a UAC the other is something else entirely different

Comment: @Ramhound Both are warning me about an unknown publisher asking for admin rights. So what's the difference between the two pop ups contextually.

Comment: @Muffined - One is requesting you elevate the permissions to make changes to your system the other is warning you of the reputation of the file.  Smart Screen uses a global history of the file, signing an executable, increases that reputation

Answer (score 2):

From the [Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/how-user-account-control-works):

> The elevation prompt color-coding is as follows:
>
> - Red background with a red shield icon: The app is blocked by Group Policy or is from a publisher that is blocked.
> - Blue background with a blue and gold shield icon: The application is a Windows 10 and Windows 11 administrative app, such as a Control
>   Panel item.
> - Blue background with a blue shield icon: The application is signed by using Authenticode and is trusted by the local computer.
> - Yellow background with a yellow shield icon: The application is unsigned or signed but is not yet trusted by the local computer.